# Validating ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,1,0)[12] with manual calculation

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, autoregressive

I am using the `forecast` package in R to do ARIMA forecasting with `auto.arima()` function by Professor Hyndman.

I have 27 months of sales data (June 2014 to August 2016), I'm using the first 21 months as training set, and the rest 6 months as test set.

```
dataset <- c(380075, 367137, 320548, 290192, 256514, 365335, 356847, 287760, 378703, 415378, 331637, 228744, 407655, 496475, 340695, 410041, 725069, 594173, 614646, 530843, 565057, 487604, 565945, 410603, 405337, 283004, 211718) 
datasets = ts(dataset, start=c(2014,6), frequency=12)
trainsets <- window(datasets, end=time(datasets)[length(dataset)-6])
testsets <- window(datasets, start=time(datasets)[length(dataset)-5])
fit <- auto.arima(trainsets, ic='aic', D=1, seasonal=TRUE, approximation=FALSE,trace=TRUE, stepwise=FALSE, allowdrift=FALSE)
WA <- forecast(fit, 6)
```

And I got the return

```
> fit
Series: trainsets 
ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,1,0)[12]                    

Coefficients:
         ar1
      0.7148
s.e.  0.1989

sigma^2 estimated as 2.489e+10:  log likelihood=-120.32
AIC=244.63   AICc=246.63   BIC=245.03

> WA

Point          Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95    Hi 95
Mar 2016       548576.1 346405.21 750747.0  239382.42 857769.8
Apr 2016       426841.5 178337.38 675345.5   46787.27 806895.6
May 2016       296792.2  27678.71 565905.7 -114781.35 708365.7
Jun 2016       456293.0 177237.44 735348.6   29514.34 883071.7
Jul 2016       531239.4 247238.93 815239.9   96898.14 965580.7
Aug 2016       365543.2  79049.34 652037.0  -72611.33 803697.7
```

I tried to do the manual calculation to understand the output, so because I have ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,1,0)[12]

So I expect the calculation to be

$$\hat{Y_t}(1) = \mu + \phi*(Y_{t-1} - Y_{t-2}) + Y_{t-12}$$

I think I can leave the $\mu$ = 0

So, for the March 2016 with the forecast of 548576.1, I calculate

$$\hat{Y_t}(MARCH2016) = 0 + 0.7148*(FEB2016 - JAN2016) + MARCH2015$$
$$\hat{Y_t}(MARCH2016) = 0 + 0.7148*(565057 - 530843) + 415378$$
$$\hat{Y_t}(MARCH2016) = 589513.1672$$

**Question :**  What makes my calculation doesn't meet the correct forecasting? Can you please suggest me the right way to calculate the function?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you got the model equation right. The model is (omitting the intercept) $x_t=\varphi_1 x_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$ where $x_t=(y_t-y_{t-12})$. Insert the latter expression of $x$ into the first equation, and you will get something different than you have now.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I tried to calculate the way you suggest me, but I think I got lost and needs to be clear. In your formula, what does Xt, Yt, and Et actually means? 
What I got is, Et for error term (but I don't know if there's exist in my ARIMA, so I leave it 0), Xt forecasted value?, and Yt is my actual sales? Or I'm getting wrong here? Thanks.

@RichardHardy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is 
$$
x_t=\varphi_1 x_{t−1}+\varepsilon_t
$$ where $x_t=(y_t−y_{t−12})$. Insert the latter expression into the equation above to get
$$
(y_t - y_{t-12}) = \varphi_1 (y_{t-1} - y_{t-13}) + \varepsilon_t,
$$ 
thus 
$$
y_t = y_{t-12} + \varphi_1 (y_{t-1} - y_{t-13}) + \varepsilon_t.
$$
When you forecast one step ahead, you get 
\begin{aligned}
\hat y_{t+1|t} &= y_{t-12+1} + \varphi_1(y_{t-1+1} - y_{t-13+1}) + \hat\varepsilon_{t+1|t} \\
&= y_{t-11} + \varphi_1(y_{t} - y_{t-12}) + 0 \\
&= y_{t-11} + \varphi_1(y_{t} - y_{t-12}). \\
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you for your brief explanation, I have tried your suggestion there, and the answer become more close to the auto.arima forecasting result.

Here is the result I got :
For my March 2016 forecast, I calculate with your suggested equation as follow :

$$ \hat{y}_t(MARCH2016) = \{y}_t(MARCH2015) + 0.7148 * \{y}_t(FEB2016) - \{y}_t(FEB2015) $$
$$ = 415378 + 0.7148 * ( 565057 - 378703 ) $$
$$ = 548583.8392 $$

Expected : 548576.1

There was a little difference with the expected output in `WA$mean` variable, was I wrong in calculating the quotation?

Thank you @richard

Comment: Can it be a rounding problem or something? Maybe try using `coef(fit)[1]` instead of 0.7148 in your manual calculation.

Comment: Oh yea! Finally, it is actually a rounding problem on the coefficient, I just recheck by calling the function `coef(fit)` and found different result of my ar1, which is 0.7147584, not 0.7148 as displayed on the `fit` calls. Thank you so much Richard.

Comment: @ErvanSanjaya, I am glad to have been able to help.

Comment: Richard, I have another question, actually I don't really get it how you can say 

"where `xt=(yt−yt−12)xt = (yt−yt−12)`. Insert the latter ..."

At this point, I'm kinda confused to fit each model to calculate manually. I have this following model to be manually calculated : 

ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,1,0)
ARIMA(3,1,0)(0,1,0)
ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,1,0)
ARIMA(0,0,1)(0,1,0)
ARIMA(2,0,0)(0,1,0)
ARIMA(3,0,0)(0,1,0)
ARIMA(2,1,0)(0,1,0)
ARIMA(4,1,0)(0,1,0)
ARIMA(2,1,0)(0,1,0)

Can you give me solution on how to build the quotation to each model with a simple 'how-to'? Thanks.

Comment: continued, I just tried to manually calculate an ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,1,0)

following the previous count, the only difference is with the `d=1` in this model, so I'm thinking of this equation :

$$y_t = \varphi_1 (y_{t-1} - y_{t-2} - y_{t-13}) +  y_t - y_{t-1}) + y_t - y_{t-12}) $$

But, as I calculated it, the function does not give the correct forecasted value from that model.

Can you help me to understand the method? Because I'm kinda confused with these thing.

Comment: @ErvanSanjaya, see [these questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+model+equation), you should find quite a few relevant solutions. What I did above is separate differencing from the rest by changing variable names. So if the original variable $y_t$ is ARIMA(p,1,q), I consider $x_t$ instead that is ARIMA(p,0,q) with $x_t:=(y_t-y_{t-1})$, and similarly for seasonal integration (exactly what I did above).